# When running python3 -bb, why does set([b'foo', u'foo']) fail but set([b'foo', u'bar']) succeed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I was trying to make some code `str(bytes)` safe on Python 3 by adding the `-bb` argument, which turns both `str(bytes)` and bytes/str comparisons into an error.

> issue warnings about str(bytes_instance), str(bytearray_instance) and
>   comparing bytes/bytearray with str. (-bb: issue errors)

The program failed because a library was trying to build a set containing both `str` and `bytes`, but it doesn't reproduce interactively: `set([b'foo', u'bar'])` works. Why does only `set([b'foo', u'foo'])` fail?

Comment: Obviously it has something to do with one list containing unique strings and the other list containing a duplicate.

Comment: You have to run Python3 with the -bb argument.

Comment: The reason can probably be found somewhere [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/setobject.c#L138).

Answer (score 3):

By experiment:

- `set(['foo', b'foo'])` returns a set containing both objects
- `'foo'` and `b'foo'` hash to equal values
- therefore Python must be comparing them for equality (or the set would only have one member), hence the error is raised under `-bb`

```
>>> set(['foo', b'foo'])
{b'foo', 'foo'}
>>> hash('foo')
7554140378331821102
>>> hash(b'foo')
7554140378331821102
>>> hash('foo') == hash(b'foo')
True
>>> 'foo' == b'foo'
False
```